# Calculations <1 incorrectly coming back as 0.00 instead of a decimal

Tags: marketing-cloud, decimal

I have some logic in Marketing Cloud which divides the number of orders placed by the number of customers targeted for some comms `(Orders_pp)` but this keeps bringing back 0.00 instead of 0.04. The field is set as decimal (18,2) and my other decimal fields are working but I assume that's because the other fields' results are above 1.

I have tried using round() to 1, 2 and 3 decimal places but I am still getting the same problem.

```
select [group]
        , Sales_pp = Net_sales/Customers
        , Orders_pp = Orders/Customers
        , AOV = Net_Sales/Orders
        , Net_margin_pp = Net_Margin/Customers
        , Contribution_pp = (net_margin/customers)-0.02 
from SMS_HB_CROSSTAB
```

Do I need to change the above logic if I know the result is <1?

Comment: What part of Salesforce are you using here? Marketing Cloud? This doesn't look like a SOQL query, and the answer to your question will likely differ if you're using Marketing Cloud as opposed to the Sales Cloud. You should [edit] your question to add more relevant tags.

Comment: Sorry yes I'm using Marketing Cloud!

Comment: In regular Sales Cloud salesforce, a Decimal type can only have 18 length total across numbers left and right of the decimal.  If you can adjust, try decimal (16,2) and see if that helps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might try using `cast` on each element and then on the result.  I ran into an issue like this when calculating open rates.  This method worked in my situation.

```sql
select 
  [group]
, Sales_pp = cast(cast(Net_sales as decimal(18,2)) / cast(Customers as bigint) as decimal(18,2))
, Orders_pp = cast(cast(Orders as decimal(18,2)) / cast(Customers as bigint) as decimal(18,2))
, AOV = cast(cast(Net_sales as decimal(18,2)) / cast(Orders as bigint) as decimal(18,2))
, Net_margin_pp = cast(cast(net_margin as decimal(18,2)) / cast(Customers as bigint) as decimal(18,2))
, Contribution_pp = cast(cast(net_margin as decimal(18,2)) / cast(Customers as bigint) as decimal(18,2))
from SMS_HB_CROSSTAB
```

Comment: The syntax was erroring but I added an extra 'case' and it's worked, thank you! 

cast((cast(Orders as decimal(18,2)) / cast(Customers as bigint)) as decimal(18,2))

Comment: Great! I've updated my answer to provide valid syntax.